# Can't access USB hard drive plugged in to Time Capsule

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sharing, time-capsule

I have the most recent 2 TB Time Capsule to which I connected (via USB) a 1.5 TB Seagate hard drive.

I expect the hard drive to be visible under "Shared", but nothing appears, except the Time Capsule itself.

The hard drive has two partitions on it, one NTFS and the other Mac OS Extended. The hard drive works just fine when connected directly to my Mac. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I see the same symptoms on my setup-- Used to use the usb hdd all the time on my old Windows setup, am able to see it on my macbook just fine. We are probably working in NTFS which, however, is clearly not allowed:

> Note: ExFAT and NTFS formats aren't supported.

Per http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2426